# object mysteriously getting deallocated

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm having an issue with an object that gets deallocated somehow someway. I have used the various debugging techniques like enabling NSZombie etc to find the problematic object. It is a simple NSMutable Array object that I used to display my section header title in a grouped tableview. It is the object from which the title header is returned in the function:

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

where I return the value using objectAtIndex on the object mentioned above. I have ensured that it doesn't run out of bounds or anything. This grouped tableView appears on the left side of my custom splitView controller. It all works fine in portrait mode where the left side comes in a popover. No issues. In landscape where it appears as a table I have this object deallocating itself mysteriously. The split view appears first no issues. Then I have a modal view coming on top of it. It is when I dismiss this modal view on top, the section header object deallocates mysteriously crashing the split view underneath the modal which tries to appear on the modal dismiss.

Any pointers or clues?

Thanks

Comment: Show us your variable declarations, properties, where it is being used, and any other related code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without code it will be really hard to find the problem.

Does the crash happen on a real device, the simulator or both? Are you retain/allocating and releasing the object manually or is it in a auto release pool?

Generally check your `viewDidUnload`, `viewWillDisappear`, `didReceiveMemoryWarning` methods and make sure everything you release is recreated in the appropriate methods.
If you are using that array in multiple view controllers make sure to retain and release it in every view controller at the appropriate points.

One way to find out who is releasing the array would be:

Creating a subclass of NSMutableArray

```
@interface myNSMutableArray : NSMutableArray {}
@end

@implementation myNSMutableArray
-(oneway void)release {
    NSLog(@"Being released");
    NSLog(@"retainCount: %i", [self retainCount]);
    [super release];
}
@end
```

Change the type of your mystery array to `myNSMutableArray`, add a break point after the 2 NSLog lines and when the debugger arrives at the breakpoint ask GDB for a backtrace (`bt` command).

Comment: Thanks for all the input. Code-wise well there is nothing really to post except that it is a NSMutable array declared in the interface and initialized in the viewDidLoad of the tableView. I have checked everywhere and ensured that I do not release it. I even tried manually retaining it. No use. Crashes on the simulator. And this tableView is the only controller which uses this object. I've tried the usual alloc-init as well as alloc-initWithArray and made sure I do not release it at all & manually retain it. Hope that helps.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a debug option, try it. The backtrace of your crash might be useful too. If release never get called consider doing the same for `dealloc` + `NSLog(@"retain count %i", retainCount);`

Comment: Thanks! Your input helped. Although it does not explain why. But I made a mistake mentioning the detail. The array was not declared in the interface. It was a global in the implementation. Changed it to interface variable and manually retained it. worked. The backtrace NSLog sure helped me realize that it was a global in the implementation who's memory was somehow getting deallocated suddenly despite retaining. The only difference was I moved the declaration to the interface and made it a class variable for it to work.

Comment: This is a good brute force debugging technique, but the mention of `retainCount` is nonsense.  Especially in the context of `dealloc`.  If it is a spurious `dealloc`, use the subclass and set a breakpoint on `dealloc`.  If it is an over-release, Instruments would be a better option than this, but this works too -- no need for `retainCount`.

Comment: @bbum I agree that in most case there is a easier way of finding the issue. However since the questioner did not provide any code it was the first thing I could come up with. I haven't used Instruments much. While you are right regarding `dealloc`, I just thought it wouldn't hurt. I also corrected `retainCount` to `[self retainCount]`.

Answer (score 0):

When you load (or reload) your array, did you retain it?